# Calculate total of input text fields on a datatable in jsf

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2

I have a JSF `<h:datatable>` with two columns.

- column 1 : `<h:outputText>`, gets populated from bean data.
- coulmn 2 : `<h:inputText>` boxes.

There is a "Total" field outside the table and I want to have it show the total of fields as entered in column2 in realtime. So I did searching around and found out that I need a JavaScript to do this. I am however quite new to JS.

Where I am confused is how to access the value of the input text box. What I have done so far:

```
function totalFrom() {
    var element = document.getElementById('transferFundsForm:fundsFromTable:0:from_transferAmt');
    if(element != null){
        document.forms['transferFundsForm']['transferFundsForm:totalFrom'].value = document.forms['transferFundsForm']['transferFundsForm:totalFrom'].value+ element;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, the `transferFundsForm:fundsFromTable:0`, here `0` represents the first row. How do I refer to the element in column that is being edited?

I have called this function on `onblur` event of the textBox in column.

Also I read that I can use `<f:ajax>` for this as well, but I am using JSP instead of Facelets, so I can't use `<f:ajax>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML DOM element representation of `<table>` element has a [`rows` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.rows) which gives you an array of all `<tr>` elements. The HTML DOM representation of this `<tr>` element has a [`cells` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/tableRow.cells) which gives you an array of all `<td>` elements.

So, provided that the 2nd column of the table contains only one `<input>` element which holds the value you'd like to sum up, and that `totalFrom` is an `<input>` element (at least, you're attempting to set the `value` property and not `innerHTML`), you could achieve this as follows:

```
function totalFrom() {
    var table = document.getElementById('transferFundsForm:fundsFromTable');
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var secondColumn = table.rows[i].cells[1];
        var input = secondColumn.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        var value = parseInt(input.value);

        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            total += value;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('transferFundsForm:totalFrom').value = total;
}
```

If the `totalFrom` is however a `<h:outputText id="totalFrom">`, then set it as follows instead:

```
    document.getElementById('transferFundsForm:totalFrom').innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: thanks :) , btw I had a question related to this. This function gets invoked properly on `onblur` event. But when I call it on `onchange` nothing happens. Is there some reasoning for that? or I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Change the value before leaving the field.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the jsf server side event or user 
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/
it also provide you builtin ajax functionality

Comment: Server side? you sure? if it can be done on client side with javaScript why go for server side and unnecessarily increase traffic?

Comment: @Mukul why have a server at all? We did pretty well without them throughout the
80-ties and early 90-ties.

Comment: @MikeBraun: I think you dint get my point.. still just an FYI it is 2013 not 80s/90s

Comment: @Mukul but can't we just do everything on the client again? Didn't you mean to say that using a server is so 00-ties? Indeed, it's 2013 now, the return of the client and away with the server?

Comment: @MikeBraun what I meant was, this is client side stuff.. I need to update the counter on UI(Client Side) when data is entered on UI(Client Side) when this thing can be more easily, neatly, swiftly and logically done on UI(Client Side) then its better to do it on client side and save us unnecessary round about trip(s) to server